# zoom and select-elements in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

This code:

```
<select>
    <OPTION value="Aston Martin">Aston Martin</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="Alfa Romeo">Alfa Romeo</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</OPTION>
</select>
```

...renders this:

[image]

If you use IE8 and press ctrl + '+' three times to zoom in you get this:

[image]

The box is not resizing. If you make IE8 go into "compatibility view" it grows the box (but when zooming out, it does not shring the box...).

Is there any way of not having to go into companibility view and still have the box resize itself on zoom? Compatability view comes with some other problems...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, provide IE8 users with the following link: http://browsehappy.com/